# Coefficients from linear sum of matrices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have a basis set of square matrices and a data set that I need to find the coefficients for given that my data is a linear sum of the basis set.

```py
def basis(a,b,c):
    return a*gam1+b*gam2+c*kapp+allsky
```

So data = basis and I need the best fit (least square) values of the coefficients `a`,`b` and `c`. The basis matrices and the data matrices are all square matrices of 89x89. I have tried using `np.linalg.lstsq` however since my A matrix would need to be a matrix of the 4 basis matrices the array dimension becomes 4 and throws an error stating the array dimension must be 2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What would be the data types of all the variables in your code? Which ones are matrixes (I assume `np.ndarray`) and which ones are floats or ints?

Comment: `a`,`b` and `c` should all come out as float (real numbers) all other data types are matrices (currently 89x89 square containing real floats)